# IOS Why does a view have 2 Custom Classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

Probably quite a simple question but I have not seen it addressed so far (I am a ios newbie)

So I start Xcode and create a simple (leave it Blank) view controller in Storyboard.

Click at the bottom so that it highlights in blue allows me to assign that view to a Controller that I am creating.

Thats found under the Custom Class field in xcode

Now if I click anywhere inside that blank view I see that Custom Class reference has changed.
Its now reffering to something else and not my Custom Controller that it was just pointing to.

What is this custom Class a reference to ?

What do I need to use if for ?

Does my view have 2 custom classes associated to it ??

Anyway as you can see I am confused by this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When you click inside the controller, you're clicking on the controller's view, not the controller itself, so you're seeing its class (which should be UIView if you haven't changed it).

Comment: So what can I do ? maybe manipulate UI's in some way ? But I effectively do that from the Controller. For example the Controller has the references to for example TextFields and from the Controller class I can populate the TextField. I assume I can even manipulate the Text and font size from within the controller. So in what ways do I need to interact with the the controllers view class ?

Comment: @drlobo, it's hard to answer that question in the abstract. You may not have to interact with it at all. Often the controllers main view is just a UIView (not subclassed), and you don't need to interact with it at all except maybe to set its color. You get a reference to it in your controller with self.view